# How to shorten this expression?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I can't figure out how to make this code work faster, where:

`a`  is a dataframe (`a[i]`  is a list of values, `a[i][4], a[i][5]`  are certain values);

`if type(a[i][5])==float`  - this is checking if the value is `NaN`

`b`  - is a list

So my a is too big and this code is being processed for 2 minutes. Can you help me speed it up, please?)

````
for i in range(len(a)):
    if a[i][4] != a[i][5]:
        if type(a[i][5])==float:
            b.append(1)        
        else:
            b.append(a[i][5])  ```
````

Comment: Providing an input dataframe & an expected output dataframe along with the description has better chance of getting you a good answer quickly.

Comment: I dont quite follow why do you have for `i in range(len(a))` written twice?? typo or does it do something???

Comment: Unfortunately, it's quite hard to execute:( But at the same time I want to find out the principle, and it's not up to the certain input, isn't it?.

Comment: Mc Missile, I corrected it.

Comment: are you using map to run that function?

Comment: No, I commit the direct function calling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> if a[i][4] != a[i][5]
> ```

Looks like you are comparing rows four and five of each column based on your indexing.

Here is a roundabout way of doing it.

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(110).reshape((11,10)))
df.iloc[5,5] = np.nan
df.iloc[4,8] = 58
```

Notice rows four and five are the same in column eight (both equal 58).

```
>>> df.iloc[4:6,:]
    0   1   2   3   4     5   6   7   8   9
4  40  41  42  43  44  45.0  46  47  58  49
5  50  51  52  53  54   NaN  56  57  58  59
```

Find all the columns where rows four and five are different.

```
noteql = df.iloc[4,:] != df.iloc[5,:]    # noteql is a boolean Series
```

*Get* row five of all the `noteql` columns using [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html?highlight=boolean).

```
b = df.loc[5,noteql]
```

[Replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#the-where-method-and-masking) all [NaN](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.notna.html) values with `1`

```
b = b.where(b.notna(),1)
# or
#b.where(b.notna(),1,inplace=True)
# for older versions of pandas
#b.where(b.notnull(),1,inplace=True)
```

Make a list

```
b = b.to_list()
```

---

The value 58 is missing and the NaN is replaced with `1`.

```
>>> b
[50.0, 51.0, 52.0, 53.0, 54.0, 1.0, 56.0, 57.0, 59.0]
```